# Image subtraction with CUDA and textures

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

My goal is to use C++ with CUDA to subtract a dark frame from a raw image. I want to use textures for acceleration. The input of the images is cv::Mat with the type CV_8UC4 (I use the pointer to the data of the cv::Mat). This is the kernel I came up with, but I have no idea how to eventually subtract the textures from each other:

```
__global__ void DarkFrameSubtractionKernel(unsigned char* outputImage, size_t pitchOutputImage,
cudaTextureObject_t inputImage, cudaTextureObject_t darkImage, int width, int height)
{
    const int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    const float tx = (x + 0.5f);
    const float ty = (y + 0.5f);

    if (x >= width || y >= height) return;

    uchar4 inputImageTemp = tex2D<uchar4>(inputImage, tx, ty);
    uchar4 darkImageTemp = tex2D<uchar4>(darkImage, tx, ty);

    outputImage[y * pitchOutputImage + x] = inputImageTemp - darkImageTemp; // this line will throw an error
}
```

This is the function that calls the kernel (you can see that I create the textures from unsigned char):

```
void subtractDarkImage(unsigned char* inputImage, size_t pitchInputImage, unsigned char* outputImage,
size_t pitchOutputImage, unsigned char* darkImage, size_t pitchDarkImage, int width, int height, 
cudaStream_t stream)
{
    cudaResourceDesc resDesc = {};
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
    resDesc.res.pitch2D.width = width;
    resDesc.res.pitch2D.height = height;
    resDesc.res.pitch2D.devPtr = inputImage;
    resDesc.res.pitch2D.pitchInBytes = pitchInputImage;
    resDesc.res.pitch2D.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(8, 8, 8, 8, cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned);

    cudaTextureDesc texDesc = {};
    texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
    texDesc.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
    texDesc.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeBorder;

    cudaTextureObject_t imageInputTex, imageDarkTex;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaCreateTextureObject(&imageInputTex, &resDesc, &texDesc, 0));

    resDesc.res.pitch2D.devPtr = darkImage;
    resDesc.res.pitch2D.pitchInBytes = pitchDarkImage;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaCreateTextureObject(&imageDarkTex, &resDesc, &texDesc, 0));

    dim3 block(32, 8);
    dim3 grid = paddedGrid(block.x, block.y, width, height);

    DarkImageSubtractionKernel << <grid, block, 0, stream >> > (reinterpret_cast<uchar4*>(outputImage), pitchOutputImage / sizeof(uchar4),
    imageInputTex, imageDarkTex, width, height);


    CUDA_CHECK(cudaDestroyTextureObject(imageInputTex));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaDestroyTextureObject(imageDarkTex));
}
```

The code does not compile as I can not subtract a uchar4 from another one (in the kernel). Is there an easy way of subtraction here?

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Visual Studio shows: no operator "-" matches these operands;
operand types are: uchar4 - uchar4

Comment: That is a pretty straightforward error. There are no operators other than assignment defined for any of the CUDA built-in vector types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an easy way of subtraction here?

There are no arithmetic operators defined for CUDA built-in vector types. If you replace

```
outputImage[y * pitchOutputImage + x] = inputImageTemp - darkImageTemp;
```

with

```
uchar4 val;
val.x = inputImageTemp.x - darkImageTemp.x;
val.y = inputImageTemp.y - darkImageTemp.y;
val.z = inputImageTemp.z - darkImageTemp.z;
val.w = inputImageTemp.w - darkImageTemp.w;
outputImage[y * pitchOutputImage + x] = val;
```

things will work. If this offends you, I suggest writing a small library of helper functions to hide the mess.

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking into the definition of uchar4 and saw that is defined as a struct of 4 single unsigned chars. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I do not want to be nit-picky, but the 4th value of uchar4 is "w" and not "h" (at least on my system).

Comment: @GreenCoder: that was a typo on my behalf